# drupal 7 email node / task list

Tags: drupal-7

Somewhat new to drupal 7 and am pretty stumped by this one.

I have content type tasks with field Responsible which is entity from authenticated users list. The system is used only by 10~20 people.

8am in the morning, I need to email list of these tasks (node:title) to users marked Responsible for their tasks.

I am banging my head around but can't seem to figure out how to go about this. Have been through Views, VBO, Rules but no luck. Been able to get as far as getting a view with a group by email. (Relationship in the view to join field on user to user email).

ANY help / pointers appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view using Views UI which would accept user id as a contextual input.

Then create a custom module.
With hook_menu define

1. a custom url which can be called by the cron
2. a custom callback function to run your code

in your call back function loop through each user and call the respective view programmatically using 
use the following to get result as html,

```
views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default' , $uid );
```

or use the following to get result as array.

```
views_get_view_result(($name, $display_id = 'default' , $uid );
```

with each result send mail to the corresponding user using [drupal_mail();](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)

Define (on your server) a cron job scheduling the actions. Make it run everyday at eight am and visit the menu created by your custom module.

Later on for performance improvement and better mail handling, you can try to incorporate [Queue API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7) in core. Also be aware about server time-zones when you configure the cron jobs. It might be set to something different than expected.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer D34dman. That sounds a bit complicated and beyond me for the moment :(. I would have expected something in rules could handle it? a component maybe?

Comment: lemme try out something if this could be done entirely in GUI. I will post that answer if i could figure out. But the weekend is over, so i would be quite busy :(

Comment: Ok, I have changed tactics here. I will setup a content type called "User Preferences" where I will store a list of tasks for each user. I have been able to get the framework working in principle with rules and vbo. The +ive of this is that users can also store their preferences for reminders and other stuff in the future. I will still look forward to any suggestions and will post progress..